# How to add a comma at the end of a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dict with a tuple as a key and list of list of float as value:

input

```
{('K', 123): [[34.0, 34.0], [0.92, 1.5]], ('P', 799): [[14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0], [5.6, 16.7, 12.34, 56.7]], ('H', 946): [[14.5, 56.5, 10.0], [0.34, 0.98, 0.78]]}
```

output

```
{('K', 123): 34.0, ('P', 799): 14.0, ('H', 946): 27,}
```

I have to find the average at key[0] (the answer is the output), however everytime I run my code, I get this

```
{('K', 123): 34.0, ('P', 799): 14.0, ('H', 946): 27}
```

the comma at the very end is missing. Is there a way to add it?

This is the code I am using:

```
def average(whole_thing: dict[tuple[str, int], list[list[float]]]) -> dict[tuple[str, int], float]

empty_dict = {}

for t in whole_thing:
    value = whole_thing[t]
    empty_dict[t] = sum(value[0])/len(value[0])
return empty_dict
```

how can I make it so that it adds the comma at the end? I know it is not necessary to have it, but i need it.

Comment: Your function is returning a dict type. The comma that is missing is to do with how the dict is printed. If you want the dict to be printed differently then wrap the __str__ or __repr__ method of the dict.

Comment: Your desired output would be an invalid dict, whatever you're comparing it to is malformed.

Comment: @jhylands means the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods, the underscores caused his text to be bold.

Comment: `{('K', 123): 34.0, ('P', 799): 56.0, ('H', 946): 27,}` is a valid well-formed dict literal: it's optional to have a comma after the last key-value pair (as with lists and with tuples bigger than one element).  The problem is the way it's printed, as @jhylands says.

Comment: Why do you need a comma at the end? Dictionaries and lists can be entered with an extra comma at the end, but they're not automatically printed that way, and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: i am sorry but where and how can i add the __str__? with empty_dict[t]??

Comment: @Barmar my doctest keep returning an error because of the missing comma

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your doctest tests, they're looking for something they shouldn't be.

Comment: and how can i change the way it is printed? where can I add the methods? @slothrop

Comment: @knsfcs you could create a subclass of dict and wrap either `__str__` or `__repr__`, and have your function return that instead of a plain old dict.  But that seems a bit perverse for the sake of the doctest: better to fix the expected result in the doctest so it corresponds to the standard way that Python prints dicts.

Comment: @j1-lee, yes there was an error, I just modified that, but even with that, I still get an error because of the missing comma